Why does Cambridge dictionary use present unreal conditional to describe past real conditional?
As I know from many sources, the form of the present unreal conditional is like the following:
If + simple past + would + verb's base form.
However, I have encountered this form used in dictionary.cambridge to describe the past real conditional.

If we wanted someone to fix something, we would ask our neighbour. He was always ready to help. (Every time we wanted someone, we would ask our neighbour.)

As I learned the past real conditional is supposed to be like this:
If we wanted someone to fix something, we always asked our neighbour. He was always ready to help.
If we wanted someone to fix something, we used to ask our neighbour. He was always ready to help.

You've obviously misunderstood something. If we wanted someone to fix something, we would ask our neighbour could refer to #1 actual habitual behaviour in the past, OR to #2 an "unreal, timeless" situation. Context determines which applies. In your case, the additional context He was always ready to help forces interpretation #1, obviously).

Saleh, listen to me: If + present or past is still spoken in the  present about the possibilities. If I go, you will see me. If I went, you would see me.  Future unreal conditional does not exist.

+1.  @SalehRezq       Although all Conditional sentences are included in the Cambridge dictionary, they aren’t commonly taught in many schools (as I learned from ELL). Your question is a good one and will be helpful for those learning Conditionals.

we would as the past tense of will can have the meaning "it was our practice":

If we needed something fixed, we would ask our neighbor, who was a handyman.

"If we needed something fixed" can mean "whenever we needed something fixed." It was our practice to ask our neighbor whenever we needed something fixed.
But we can use the same forms to speak of a hypothetical situation rather than a real recurrent past situation:

If I needed something fixed in our new house, I would consider doing it myself.

That is, "Should I ever encounter a situation where something in our new house  needed to be repaired", then "I would weigh the pros and cons of doing it myself".

If + simple past + would + verb's base form used to describe present unreal and future unreal conditionals. Then you cannot tell it is describing real past conditional without adding more information "who was a handyman" or "He was always ready to help". Am I right?.

@SalehRezq Correct, but I would refine your statement. You cannot tell from the form of the utterance, without additional information, whether it is present irrealis or a past real condition, but the additional information may be available in the context of the conversation. If the conversation was about the past, a reasonable interlocutor should assume that you are talking about what you used to do, and not suddently interjecting a present hypothetical, as that would be a non sequitur.

OP has enquired about the Past Real Conditional taken from the Cambridge dictionary:

If we wanted someone to fix something, we would ask our neighbour. He was always ready to help. (Every time we wanted someone, we would ask our neighbour.)

In OP's case the sentence,
"He was always ready to help." indicates that the given sentence is Real and not hypothetical.
Though the structure looks similar to the Second Conditional
("If + past simple, would + infinitive"), this is a Past Real Conditional.
The  if-clause describes a real past situation, and the main clause uses "would" to mean "used to," indicating repeated actions or habits in the past.
Example:
I would cry if anyone touched my Barbie doll (when I was a kid).
The Past Real Conditional describes repeated actions or habits in the past that occurred whenever a specific condition was met. It uses:

If-clause: Simple past (describing the condition in the past).
Main clause: "Would" + base verb (indicating habitual actions, similar to "used to").

This structure reflects real past habits, not hypothetical situations.
Relevant Links:

1. Used to, Would.
We only use 'would' to describe actions or situations that were repeated again and again and again.
But we use 'used to' for any extended action or situation in the past.
When he was at school, he used to play football every Saturday.".
Here, we're talking about 'playing football every Saturday'. This is an action that was repeated many times, so we can also say:
"When he was at school, he would play football every Saturday".
'Used to' and 'would' are both good here, and the meaning is the same.


2. Past Conditionals real and unreal.
The Past Real Conditional describes what you used to do in particular real-life situations. It suggests that your habits have changed and you do not usually do these things today.

If I went out with my friends, I usually spent the whole night out. I can’t do that anymore..
When I had time off, I always travelled. Now I’m too busy..
When he was younger, he walked everywhere. Now he uses his car..
I had more time for my hobbies when I was younger.



englishpage puts this form under Present Unreal Conditional I would read more if I didn't watch so much TV. Is the website wrong?

So the bottom line goes: Present Unreal Conditional = I would read more if I didn't watch so much TV. Future Unreal Conditional = Tomorrow, I would read more if I didn't watch so much TV. Past Real Conditional = I would read more if I didn't watch so much TV. (we can add "as a child" or "when I was young" or "yesterday" and so on. I know there are other forms specifically dedicated to future and present conditionals. However, all of the three tenses share the same conditional form in question; with extra information or context to understand which tense it belongs to.

@SalehRezq   The Present Unreal Conditional and the Future Unreal Conditional both resemble the Second Conditional. However, if you use "yesterday," it shifts to the Third Conditional, as it refers to an unreal past situation. The Past Real Conditional is typically used for regular habits in the past. However, using it in negative sentences can create ambiguity, making it appear more like a Third Conditional.
